# How to move to next slide programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, supersized

I am using the following code to initialize the [supersized plugin](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#api-nextslide):

```
$.supersized({
    slides  :   [ 
        { image : '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/bkg/1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Anna Tifu' },
        { image : '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/bkg/3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Anna Tifu' },
        { image : '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/bkg/3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Anna Tifu' }
    ]
});
```

How can I tell my menu to navigate next and prev?

Something like this?

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    slides.next();
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should take a look into the documentation: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#api-nextslide

Comment: i'm not too sure where i should be inserting this tho:

      $(element).click(function(){
 api.nextSlide();
   });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#api_docs

You have 2 methods namely `nextSlide()` and `prevSlide()`